# Simple unix program to automatically copy file from usb to hard disk

Tags: unix

Please tell me a simple unix program to automatically copy a file or folder to the hard disk when the usb disk is inserted into the usb-port

Answer (score 0):

There are simple ways of copying files over from disks, mainly `cp`, however there is no way to 'autorun' scripts on a flash drive, unless you use a cron job, or maybe edit some udev rules, however I'm not sure udev can run shell scripts.

If it can, they can only be run from the host filesystem; not the USB disk.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write a program that listens for the particular DBUS event, A dirtier way might be to grep dmesg every few seconds for your device, when it finds it use cp or rsync to transfer the files.

Answer (score 0):

Write udev rule. Something like this:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="USB 2.0 Storage Device", RUN+="/somewhere/copy.sh"
```

You can find more information on udev rules here: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd

Edit: on ubuntu you need to put this rule to /etc/udev/rules.d/80-usbcopy.rules